# how to clear NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath

On running my java program for file copy to hdfs i am get following exceptions

```
hduser@master:~/Desktop/Source Code$ java -cp . Filesize monis.txt /home/hduser/Desktop/Source*/monis.txt /tmp/user/gutenberg



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at FileSize.copyFromLocal(FileSize.java:219)
at FileSize.main(FileSize.java:74)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 2 more
```

i have defined my `CLASSPATH` variable in `/etc/environment` file and it looks like such

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" 

CLASSPATH="/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/hduser/Desktop/Source*/"
```

Still I am getting this exception.

Comment: Make sure that the path to the jar in which the above file is meant to reside, is correct.

Comment: This may not be the problem but `/home/hduser/Desktop/Source*/` is not valid.  I believe you want `/home/hduser/Desktop/Source/*`

Comment: @anuj balan ! all path to jar files are correct !

Comment: @ Jim Garrison! That path is valid , I have just used wild character to denote Source code directory !

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using the hadoop script to lanch this program (and this dealing with the classpath for you?). Can you post how you are currently launching the program

Comment: @Chris White ! I have edited my question for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be careful mixing the CLASSPATH environment variable and the `-cp` flag to java - which is most probably overriding the environment variable you've set in your /etc/environment.

You should also check that the changes you've made to /etc/environment have taken affect:

```
#> echo $CLASSPATH
```

If this doesn't show the values you've set then you most probably need to restart your shell session, log out and in again, or you could just source the file:

```
#> source /etc/environment
```

On a side note, the best way to run programs that interact with hadoop is via the hadoop shell script. You'll need to bundle up your classes into a jar file, but then it's easy to invoke your program, letting the script take care of adding the hadoop and other library dependencies to the classpath:

```
#> /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop myJar.jar \
      Filesize monis.txt \
      /home/hduser/Desktop/Source*/monis.txt \
      /tmp/user/gutenberg
```

Comment: @ Chris White ! Your's Side Note Helped A lot , saved much of my time ! Now i dont need to be concerned about classpath settings ! Thanks a ton !